# Swift 3 Generic cannot convert value of type UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics, swift3

I have a custom cell that can accept a generic type.

```
class MyCell<T>: UITableViewCell where T: MyCellDataSource, T: MyCellDelegate
```

How do I use it or type cast or infer it when dequeueing a cell?

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
```

Comment: you can do `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell` I think

Comment: nope, that won't do. that's the usual way and i've tried it.

Comment: You can't cast to a unspecified generic type, only a concrete version of it, i.e., with generic `T` specified. Something along the lines `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell<SomeConcreteValidType>`.

Comment: @dfri yes i know that. but how exactly? as you can see in my question, i've explicitly indicated the two protocols in the class. i know the format you've given BUT i want to know exactly the correct way of doing it because as you can see, it has multiple protocol.

Comment: The protocols are just type constraints for the generic type `T`, it doesn't matter how many such you include, what is important is that some _actual concrete type_ conforms to these (which can hence be used to construct the _concrete type_ `MyCell<SomeConcreteTypeConformingToYourTypeConstraints>`). You don't want to cast to protocols as type, but to a type conforming to the type constraints blueprinted by the protocols.

Comment: @dfri, i see what you mean. totally missed that. post it as an answer so that i can mark it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0
I had recently worked with the same implementation.
I solved this by the following a code.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MyCell<TName>
//Configure cell here
return cell!
```

Hope it helps